# JSON and other parameters in data property of AJAX PUT. ASP.net Web API

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to send a JSON object and values from text boxes back to my controller, but I am having trouble. I can send just the JSON object successfully, but as soon as I add other parameters I get an error saying `the requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.` I have tried commenting out the contentType and using `Data: {viewModel: JSON.stringify(jsonData), userName: username}`, without any success (I eventually will add more string parameters). Below is my ajax and controller signature. Thanks in advance.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'api/Label',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            success: function (result) {
                // TODO
            },
            error: function (HttpRequest, textStatus, err) {
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(HttpRequest.responseText);
                $('#LabelInfo').show();
                $('#LabelInfo').text('Error: ' + response.ModelState["viewModel.Pieces"][0]);
            }
        });
```

controller signature:

> public HttpResponseMessage Put(Label viewModel, string
>   userName)

Comment: Does the Put method have [HTTPPut] as an attribute?

Comment: that still fails. I can add it to the JSON object and that works successfully, but it seems like waste of space because it will repeat the username and password for every record I return. If that is the only way however, I will have to do that